# Gradle does not show any console output

Tags: linux, centos, gradle

I try to run gradle on my CentOS machine but it does not print any output. Only stuff like **gradle -v** or **gradle -q tasks** brings some very basic information. The main problem is, that I get an compile error but it doesn't show me where it is.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
Cause: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_HOME are set. Classpath is empty. Any ideas?

```
gradle -v

Gradle 1.0-milestone-7

Gradle build time: Thursday, January 5, 2012 10:24:43 AM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.4
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 19.1-b02)
OS: Linux 2.6.18-274.17.1.el5 amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error output should show up *above* the `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception` message. `-q` provides *less* output than normal, but you can try `-i`. You can also have a look at the stack trace with `-S`. Last but not least I recommend to try a newer Gradle version (e.g. 1.0-rc-3).

Comment: The strange thing is, he only does the build task when I say `gradle -q build`. A simple gradle build does nothing and I don't get any output. I just downloaded the new gradle version and I tried './gradle' in the bin/ directory just to see what happens but nothing happens. No output.

Comment: I found something. I get the output when I run gradle with sudo but it does not work when I login to bash via root.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and realised I was following tutorials that were using a lower version of gradlew than my gradle. So for example instead of:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.13
```

Just use your gradle version or simply:

```
gradle wrapper
```

which will do so automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while Googling because I was using Gradle but my own code's console output wasn't being logged to the command line during a test. Rather than my logged output from my own debugging statements, I was only getting extremely limited output like the following:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

> Task :integrationTest

SystemTest > MyApp system test FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at SystemTest.java:40

1 test completed, 1 failed

> Task :integrationTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/me/repos/myFolder/my-app/build/reports/tests/integrationTest/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

What I found was that *the debug statements were actually being logged correctly*. I just needed to go to the referenced test output HTML file and click on the "*Standard Output*" button. Once there, all of my logged debugging statements were present.

Answer (score -1):

If the CLASSPATH is the issue, set it before you run your command; or better yet, set it in your `.bashrc` (or whatever your shell of choice is).

```
export $CLASSPATH=/path/to/java/
```